# Where to start to learning Ajax?

Tags: ajax

I want to start learning Ajax, but I don't know how to start to learn and find a good teaching material, can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536609/how-to-start-learning-ajax, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92786/what-would-be-the-best-place-to-start-learning-ajax-i-have-perl-as-a-backend, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999097/what-would-be-the-best-place-to-start-learning-ajax-i-have-php-as-a-backend, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942279/learning-ajax-where-to-search-for-online-instruction, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119459/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-ajax, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base of ajax is the object XMLHTTPRequest.

So, you could learn the W3C specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) and a tutorial at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

---

**EDIT**

Probably you use a framework, so learn about [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion:

1 - Learn what AJAX means. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) you have the wikipedia definition
2 - Review some real applications so you'll understand what you could do with this technology. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=es&q=ajax+examples&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&cad=b&cad=cbv) is your friend.
3 - Implement a "hello world" application using the very basic principles so you have a close contact, at least for one time, with the core forces behind AJAX.
4 - Play a little with any well known javascript framework with AJAX support. [jQuery](http://www.google.com/search?hl=es&q=jqeury&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) would be perfect as other people suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think you should try to do some simple AJAX requests and such without using a library such as JQuery. Just use XMLHTTPRequest, and do some simple stuff.  That way you'll understand what JQuery is doing underneath.  If you're designing a site with a lot of AJAX, then you'll want to move over to something like JQuery, so you don't have to worry about cross-browser compatibility.  However I think that understanding how things work underneath can be very useful, and if you're just doing a couple simple things with AJAX, can actually make the page a little more compact.

Answer (score -1):

if you are going to use ASP.NET and Ajax then its very simple to learn much of the things are there which you need, just visit http://www.asp.net/ajax and there you will get each and everything you need to for a startup.

if you are using it with php then use JQuery

Comment: Better yet, just use JavaScript.