# How to change the contents of an HTML table with php + javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page which, when a user visits it, makes a MySQL call to a DB, and then puts that information into an html table presented to the viewer by the time the page initially loads.

I want to allow more advanced refinement options, like filtering by name, age, etc.

when the user submits their refinement options, how would I clear out the "old" data in the HTML table that is displayed on page load, and then re-populate it with the "new" data PHP returns?

Will this require DOM manipulation via JS? How can I specify the target node to echo out my PHP into?

Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to use AJAX to gather new information from the database and remake the table with new results. Is this right?

Comment: @Biotox: Yes! That's exactly it. Sorry I did not know the term. Do you know of any good getting-started resources for AJAX?

Comment: If you know/use jQuery, they have easy `.ajax()` function. You can just Google "jquery ajax" and find the API for it. w3schools.com also has a tutorial/basics for AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data you wish to display is available from a server and is not yet in the browser, you can make a `AJAX` call to go to the server and pull the data back from it for display.

A common use case for this is when you are displaying live information which could be periodically updated

[What is ajax?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

[Want to start learning ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536609/how-to-start-learning-ajax)

Comment: Thank you for providing links, they have gotten me off to a great start! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic java script will help you to incorporate the changes into html page.

AJAX will be the best solution to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax, Yes, document.getElementById