# Load page contents without refreshing/

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start learning Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536609/how-to-start-learning-ajax)

Is there a way to reload the page without refreshing the whole page? Like the example in the GRAPH API Explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer when ever you change the input and submit the data the it only refresh a only a part of the page, any idea on how to do something similar? Thanks

Comment: @clentfort any example or tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ check this for AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first). It can be synchronious or asynchronious.

For more information, check `XMLHttpRequest` object in javascript.

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools. It is usually out of date, often wrong, and manages to put security holes in just about every bit of example code that could have a security hole in it.

Comment: @Quentin No problem. But this one is a good demo.

Comment: and idea how can I apply this to a div element?

Comment: @Rukshan — Umm. You want to know how to apply the example *which uses a div element* to a div element?

Comment: @Rukshan did you look at xmlhttprequest ? Just change content of a div (div.innerHTML = content) in callback function `onreadystatechange`. But be sure to have readyState == 4 and status == 2xx

Comment: @quarry yes it works now :) is there a way to show a loading or message until it loads? it takes some times to load i mean like 2 3 seconds

Comment: @Rukshan just before you send the request, display some message and then call from onreadystatechange will overwrite it.

Comment: @quarry I used this to display a loading image like on FB 'document.getElementsByID('img').src="https://m-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif";' but then the ajax request fails and the loading image is not displaying, any idea why?

Comment: @Rukshan because there is an error. Its not getElement`s`ByID but getElementByID. Use error console for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called Ajax.

It is usually achieved by using the [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) to make a request to a URL designed to act as a web service end point instead of serving up a full document.

For convenience people often use a library that wraps XHR with a friendlier interface. Options include [YUI IO](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/), [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [many others](http://microjs.com/#ajax)

The web service end point often presents the data using the [JSON format](http://json.org).