# How to transfer JavaScript variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables, transfer

I've got a problem. I don't know how to transfer JS variables to PHP. 
In JS I've got my main script and I'm using PHP only to file management but I need some variables from JS.

Comment: could you add some of trying code?

Comment: javascript is clientside. Never trust javascript. Which type of variable we are talking about? consider ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is AJAX, (or SOAP but you better go with AJAX). So go do a little research on it, and if you know jQuery or Prototype or something similar, you are pretty much off for starting to code in a new technology in minutes.

Here are some links, to get you started:

[How to start learning Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536609/how-to-start-learning-ajax)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/